# Compilation results in an error when trying to compile code containing binary ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am running into a problem with the accessing a binary file via the input file stream class (ifstream).

My approach starts with the following *calling* function:

```
void ReadFile(vector<string>& argv, ostream& oss){
   string FileName = argv.at(2) + "INPUT" ;
   ifstream BinFile ;
   OpenBinaryFile(FileName, BinFile) ;
   return ;
}
```

The *called* function looks like this:

```
void OpenBinaryFile(string& FileName, ifstream& BinFile){
   using namespace std ;
   BinFile(FileName.c_str(),ifstream::binary | ifstream::in) ;
}
```

When I try to compile this simple scheme using gcc version 4.9.2 I get the following error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}) (const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode)’
BinFile(FileName.c_str(),ifstream::binary | ifstream::in) ;
                                                        ^
```

I've tried to get the caret ("^") placed exactly where the compiler did.

What's going on here? I am baffled.

Thanks!

Comment: `BinFile.open(FileName.c_str(), ifstream::binary | ifstream::in);`

Comment: That worked, but now I am even more confused. The reason I asked this question is because I've opened it in the past with out the "open" suffix. `ifstream BinFile(filename2, ios::in | ios::binary) ;` has worked elsewhere in my code.

Comment: @EmilioW: That's a declaration. The code in your question is not a declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of opening a stream.

1. During construction, in a declaration:

   ```
   std::ifstream BinFile(filename, std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::in);
   ```
2. After construction, using the `std::ifstream::open` function:

   ```
   std::ifstream BinFile;
   BinFile.open(filename, std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::in);
   ```

In your question you are attempting to mix the two. This results in an attempt to call the non-existent "function call operator" `operator()` on the object `BinFile`.

Comment: Nice, it was not aware of this nuance in syntax. I'll keep the question up as a resource to anyone undergoing a similar problem.

Comment: @Emilio: Yep seems like a fairly reasonable question. And SO exists for that exact purpose: keeping questions up for many people to be helped, not just the original asker. :)

Answer (score -1):

As written, you were calling a constructor with the object that had already been constructed on the stack of the calling routine.  See the constructor documented at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/

Comment: No, he was not calling a constructor. The closest you can get to doing that is with the typename e.g. `std::ifstream(filename, std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::in)` which is valid, but still isn't calling a constructor (not directly, anyway).

Comment: He didn't mean to, but the signature almost matched.

Comment: Nope, still not related to a constructor. It's the `operator()` he's accidentally trying to call.

Comment: @Lightness, I'd like to learn more about this.  I thought when the compiler cited any operator method, the error message would include the literal `operator` as part of that method name, like normal operator declarations as well as the symbol table.  But I am not seeing that in the OP's error message.  You're way ahead of me, so clarification is appreciated.

Comment: This is the only example I can think of of an operator that doesn't do that ;) You can still tell from the expression it _does_ show you, if you are sufficiently familiar with C++ and with GCC's error messages. Not really sure I can explain to/convince you about that in this format though.